# How do I change the Dropbox directory on a headless GNU/Linux server?

Tags: linux, dropbox

I have installed [Dropbox 2.0.0 via command line](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) on my home server (Ubuntu Server 12.04) to use for off-site automated backups, but I can't change the directory that the Dropbox daemon keeps synced.

I've tried the following:

[The official docs](https://www.dropbox.com/help/89/en) say to use the desktop application, which is not applicable in my situation. However I installed the desktop app on my desktop machine and changed the default folder location, but I can't find where this change is stored in the ~/.dropbox/ directory so I can make the same change on the server.

[This page](http://cmdlinetips.com/2012/05/how-to-change-dropboxs-default-directory-location/) (and several others) recommends [a Python script](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/119154/permalink/dropboxdir.py) to do the job. Looking at the script, it opens a SQLite database called ~/.dropbox/dropbox.db, which does not exist on my Dropbox install, leading me to believe the script is out-of-date.

[This forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1067032#p1067032) suggests manually inserting the required row in the config.db database, which I did, but it made no difference. I checked the same database file on my desktop machine, and it does not have the dropbox_path key, so I'm presuming the information in that thread is also out of date for version 2.0.

I have tried to launch the Dropbox GUI configuration wizard over SSH with X11 forwarding, as suggested in one of the answers, but the binary must detect the absence of a local X11 install and it starts a command line daemon instead, which provides no means to change the option I need.

I am currently using a symlink, as suggested as an answer, but this is a [kludge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge). I would like to know the correct way to make the change.

How do I change the Dropbox directory on a headless GNU/Linux server?

**Update:** I've ditched Dropbox and started using [Copy](https://copy.com?r=k1k4vO). Their Linux tools and support is far superior to Dropbox. I leave this question here in case someone, someday, can answer it.

Comment: My answer notwithstanding, if this is your home server why don't you just connect a screen to it, make the changes and take the screen away again?

Comment: @terdon, There is no X11 to run the Dropbox desktop app.

Comment: Ah, OK, fair enough, try my answer then, it should work. My home headless server actually has X, it is just not started by default and there is no screen attached, that's why I asked. I tested my answer on a real headless, X11-less server though and it worked. X11 forwarding uses the _local_ X server and does not need one to be running on the remote machine.

Comment: Any better options now that Copy is gone? *"Copy was discontinued on May 1, 2016. As a former Copy user, we think you'll like Trove."* - tried that?

Answer (score 11):

So here's my trick:

First I remove all related folder created in my home folder

```
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
```

I also remove Dropbox default folder:

```
rm -rf ~/Dropbox
```

So then I reinstalled dropbox daemon by define HOME env var like this:

```
HOME=/data/other_folder dropbox.py start -i
```

Next, start dropboxd daemon manually by run:

```
HOME=/data/other_folder /data/other_folder/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Then wait it till finish.

Comment: In my experience, you also need to remove ~/.dropbox, or else step 4 will complain about the computer being linked already and won't let you proceed within /data/other_folder.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Caveats: 1. Remember that your data will live in `/data/other_folder/Dropbox` 2. It will create some other dotfiles inside `other_folder`, for example when it launches your browser for the initial login. You may try clearing these up later. 3. You must use `HOME=...` every time you start dropbox. (I tried moving the `.dropbox*` folders to my real home after everything was working, but that just broke the setup.)

Answer (score 9):

You could just create a symlink to `~/Dropbox`

```
ln -s <dir-that-you-want-to-sync> ~/Dropbox
```

Comment: The question asks, "How can I change the Dropbox directory...", symlinking is not the answer.

Comment: But it takes care of the _reason_ for which you want to change the Dropbox directory, cf. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Actually. I think this won't work, I remember having trouble with symlinks not working with Dropbox.

Comment: Symlinking does work, and it's what I was using before asking this question, but it is a Kludge. I came here to find out the correct way to make the change. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to move your Dropbox folder out of your home directory, e.g. if want other users to be able to access the contents of your Dropbox folder.  ikandar's solution below worked for me, for this situation.

Answer (score 7):

This is a real shortcoming of the Linux application. In the older versions you could modify the settings file. In the most recent version it appears the only solution is to change the `$HOME` variable before Dropbox starts.

Lets say we want the 'Dropbox' folder to appear in `/foo/bar`.

1. Install Dropbox to `/foo/bar/.dropbox-dist`.
2. Download the Python script to control Dropbox from the [Linux Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) page.
3. In this script, below `import os` add a line: `os.environ["HOME"] = "/foo/bar"`
4. Dropbox controlled / started through the control script now thinks `/foo/bar/` is your `/home/username/`.

This means that when using the control script it now looks for `/foo/bar/.dropbox-dist/dropbox` to execute the daemon. Configuration files will be written to `/foo/bar/.dropbox/`. The `/foo/bar/Dropbox/` folder will be used for file synchronization.

Comment: Excellent tip! Helped a lot. Pair that with `ln -s ~/dropbox.py /usr/local/bin/dropbox` for less typing!

Comment: This works great for me, though when I attempt to stop dropbox I get a message saying `Dropbox isn't responding!`. Looks like it does stop though. A bit strange.

Comment: Interestingly enough, creating a script in `/usr/local/bin` that sets `HOME` before executing the python script (rather than modifying the script itself with `os.environ["HOME"]`) seems to have cleaned this up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I wanted to use dropbox to sync a large secondary hard disk on a ubuntu server. What I did was I created a symlink from the secondary hard disk to my home directory before installing dropbox

```
ln -s /mnt/disks/sdb /home/marc/Dropbox
```

Only install Dropbox after completing the above step.

This way, the Dropbox in the Home directory is the symlink and the real folder is where ever you symlinked from.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to make a permanent alias named dropb with the HOME-path to your new directory.

```
echo 'alias dropb="HOME=/media/your/path dropbox"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then you can use it like normal dropbox

```
dropb start -i
dropb status
dropb exclude add ./my_wife/shoe_collection
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ssh` access to the machine in question, you might be able to launch the `dropbox` desktop application on the headless server and have it displayed on your local machine:

1. Connect to the server using [X11 port forwarding](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X-Forwarding)

   ```
   ssh -Y user@server
   ```
2. Now launch the dropbox app, it should appear on your local screen

   ```
   ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
   ```

   It may take a while depending on your network connection. Don't give up if you don't get an error message. I can confirm that this worked when I connected from my Debian box to a remote, Ubuntu server that was running no X server. After a few seconds, a second Dropbox icon appeared on my local taskbar and I could access/modify the options of the remote Dropbox install from there.

Now, some details may change since I am using Dropbox 1.6.18 but the basics should be the same. In case the name or location of the app have changed, this is how I found out what command I need to execute to launch the Dropbox desktop app:

1. Get the list of currently running processes

   ```
   top -cbd .10 -n 1 | sort > no_drop.txt
   ```
2. Launch the Dropbox app (right click on the Dropbox icon in your taskbar and chose "Preferences...") and repeat

   ```
   top -cbd .10 -n 1 | sort > drop.txt
   ```
3. Compare the files to find the relevant command

   ```
   diff drop.txt no_drop.txt
   ```

Comment: There is no GUI app to forward, only dropboxd, the Dropbox daemon.

Comment: Did you try the `top` and `diff` trick I suggested? Launch the app on your local machine, something must be launched, therefore there is a command. If, in the new version, the only command is the daemon, then launch the daemon, it will still appear on your taskbar.

Comment: On my desktop machine, running ~/dropbox-dist/dropbox launches a GUI configuration wizard. On the server, through the ssh connection with X11 forwarding on, ~/dropbox-dist/dropbox launches a daemon which instructs me to go to a specific URL to 'link this machine'. Both the server and the desktop are using the exact same archive to install the dropbox files. In the archive the only two executable files are dropbox, and dropboxd, the later is just a shell script to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and launch the former.

Comment: Hmm, my remote server _has_ been linked. If I remember correctly, I had to launch a graphical browser (`lynx` couldn't do it) on the remote machine (always using X11 forwarding) and link the machine using that browser. Try doing that and then launching `~/dropbox-dist/dropbox` again. At least we have confirmed it works, the daemon you mention is graphical and is displayed on your local screen right? Therefore, once you have linked your server to your account, you should be able to configure it as described in my answer.

Comment: It was linked, I just deleted the configuration from ~/.dropbox to start from scratch. "the daemon you mention is graphical and is displayed on your local screen right?" No, it is not graphical when run on the server. It must be detecting the absence of X11 and going into command line only mode, despite X11 forwarding being on.

Comment: OK, in that case, first try running _any_ graphical program to make sure that it is possible. If it is, try doing the browser thang from my last comment. What distro do you have on your server anyway?

Comment: I installed xclock and it works over ssh, so X11 forwarding isn't the problem. The dropbox binary will not provide any GUI over ssh so I can not use it to change the directory that Dropbox synchronises.

Comment: Is that still the case after linking the server to your account? I find it very hard to believe that Dropbox would check if a server is running locally. Normally, apps will query an _accessible_ X server and one should be found in your case. I vaguely remember having to jump through a few hoops the first time I configured Dropbox on that server and having similar trouble to what you describe. I think I solved it by linking and then relaunching the Dropbox app.

Comment: Yes, that is still the case after linking the account. I have tried to relaunch the app after the linking step, but it still just starts the command line daemon on the server. I don't know why or how it behaves that way, but that's how it appears.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

[Set up Dropbox on a GUI-less Linux server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/set-up-dropbox-on-a-gui-less-linux-server/)

I apologize for simply tossing an URL instead of describing the procedures here. I'm at work and can't elaborate more right now. Later I can expand on the answer, I just don't want to lose this valuable URL with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem and was able to resolve it by

1. Unlinking the account through the Dropbox web UI:

   https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2014/10/how-to-unlink-a-device-from-your-dropbox/
2. Removing the `~/.dropbox` directory for the user running `dropboxd`.

   ```
   rm -r ~/.dropbox
   ```
3. You might need to clean up the `~/Dropbox` directory also.

The first step may be not necessary, but I'd already done that before removing `~/.dropbox`, which ultimately allowed me to set it up again.

Remember to `cd` to the directory you want to be your Dropbox root folder. 
It then worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser.  Can you elaborate on your answer?  Specifically, give a more in depth run down on what the user needs to do?

Answer (score 0):

TechRepublic has a page — [Set up Dropbox on a GUI-less Linux server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/set-up-dropbox-on-a-gui-less-linux-server) —
that claims to solve this problem:

> … There are GUI tools provided to manage the Dropbox
>   and set it up for [Linux, Windows, and OS X]. 
>   But what happens if you want to link a Linux computer
>   that doesn’t have a GUI? 
>   It is possible, with a bit of work, to make Dropbox run without a GUI,
>   allowing you to synchronize files with servers that are running headless
>   or where a user account may not be logged in all the time.
>
> ︙
>
> To begin:
>
> ```
> # mkdir -p /tmp/dropbox
> # cd /tmp/dropbox
> # curl -OL http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/6995/dbmakefakelib.py
> # curl -OL http://dl.dropbox.com/u/637552/Dropbox/dbreadconfig.py
> # curl -L -o dropbox.tar.gz http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64
> ```
>
> Use `plat=lnx.x86` if you want the 32-bit client. 
>   This creates a temporary directory for our Dropbox install files,
>   and downloads two necessary python scripts: `dbmakefakelib.py`
>   which creates fake stub copies of GUI libraries so the dropboxd daemon starts,
>   and `dbreadconfig.py` which displays dropbox configuration information.
>
> Decide which user will be running the Dropbox client;
>   this could be a dedicated user or it could be a regular user. 
>   You can also have more than one Dropbox instance running on the system,
>   so you may opt to set it up for multiple users
>   (although each user can only run one Dropbox instance). 
>   For this example, we will have created a special user “dropbox”
>   which will run this Dropbox client.
>
> ```
> # su - dropbox
> $ cd ~/
> $ tar xvzf /tmp/dropbox/dropbox.tar.gz
> $ cd .dropbox-dist
> $ python /tmp/dropbox/dbmakefakelib.py
> dropboxd ran for 15 seconds without quitting - success?
> ```
>
> The dbmakefakelib.py script requires gcc,
>   so you must have gcc installed on the system. 
>   This creates fake stub copies of the GUI libraries
>   so that dropboxd will start. 
>   At the end, you can see that it launched dropboxd; 
>   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit the script. 
>   dropboxd should still be running in the background:
>
> ```
> $ ps ax | grep dropboxd
> 24001 pts/0    S      0:00 sh -c { /home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd; } 2>&1
> ```
>
> Now that dropbox is running, we need to link it to an existing account:
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/
> $ python /tmp/dropbox/dbreadconfig.py
> host_id = 0bd9c5a15458fbc31f85e892faa7dac4
> schema_version = 6
> ```
>
> Grab the host_id from above. 
>   Login to the Dropbox web interface, and once you have logged in,
>   manually visit this URL:
>
> ```
> https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link?host_id=[HOST_ID]
> ```
>
> Replace *`[HOST_ID]`* with the host_id that dbreadconfig.py outputs. 
>   When you have done that, the Dropbox site will tell you
>   that you have successfully linked a new computer. 
>   Go to your Account settings and then My Computers
>   and you will see the new computer listed.
>
> If you have not killed the dropboxd process that dbmakefakelib.py started,
>   you will find that it is already downloading the files from the Dropbox
>   to ~/Dropbox/ in the background.
>
> To start the dropboxd daemon in the background at boot,
>   you can add the following to your /etc/rc.d/rc.local init script:
>
> ```
> daemon —user dropbox /bin/sh -c "/home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd&"
> ```
>
> This will start dropboxd in the background
>   with the privileges of the user for which it is installed
>   (in this case, the user is “dropbox”). 
>   If you want to do a system-wide initscript,
>   visit the Dropbox wiki where there are some examples you can use,
>   including initscripts for Fedora / Red Hat and for Debian / Ubuntu. 
>   It also has examples
>   for how to set up Dropbox running under DJB’s daemontools.

Comment: Thanks go to [MestreLion](https://superuser.com/users/68321/mestrelion)⁠⁠ for [posting this link](https://superuser.com/q/575550/150988#973081).